# Почему не работает подсветка Color Highlighter для модулей sass-scss?

Tags: url, sass, sublime-text, sublime-text-3, scss

Если не ставить в путь нижнее, то не работает подсветка (раньше все было ок ).

**Из документации Sass-Scss:**

> Если у Вас есть scss или sass файл, который вы хотите импортировать,
>   но не хотите его компилировать напрямую в CSS-файл, то добавьте нижнее
>   подчеркивание в начало имени файла.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S: Вышла новая версия Sublime Text 3 (может в ней проблема).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответил разработчик плагина и сказал, что он переписал его и есть недоработки.

https://github.com/Monnoroch/ColorHighlighter/issues/366